# Any way to make scatter plot for binary classification features data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, classification

I want to make a decision boundary for extracted features with binary variable columns, and I want to make a plot to separate out two class. I tried with Logistic regression to make decision boundary, but in the rendered plot, data points that belong to two class are not well separated. When I tried to make a scatter plot or decision boundary by using SVM, I have a memory error.

Is there any way I can take a sample to make scatter plot when I do SVM? how can I get correct decision boundary for binary classification? any idea?

**data**:

I have 265x16 columns dataframe of features, it is can be seen on [example data snippet on github](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/9edd9eed441d117fa3704b4eaa47001b)

**what I tried**:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pandas as pd

##  load features
df=pd.read_csv('binary_clf_feats.csv')
X_feats=df.iloc[:, 2:11,].values
y_label=df['price_status'].values
seed=np.random.seed(234)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_feats, y_label, test_size = 0.2, random_state = seed)

log_reg = LogisticRegression()
log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
parameters = log_reg.coef_[0]
parameter0 = log_reg.intercept_

# Plotting the decision boundary
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
x_values = [np.min(X_train[:,] -50 ), np.max(X_train[:,] +50 )]
y_values = np.dot((-1./parameters[1]), (np.dot(parameters[0],x_values) + parameter0))
colors=['red' if l==0 else 'blue' for l in y_train]
plt.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], label='Logistics regression', color=colors)
plt.plot(x_values, y_values, label='Decision Boundary')
plt.show()
```

but this approach gave me following plot:

[image]

I am expecting blue, red data point should be well separated. How can I manipulate my features data for getting correct scatter plot or SVM plot? any better idea to make this happen? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your dataset, you have more than 2 features. In general, 2D-plotting more than 2 features is not possible / no standard practice. You need to ask yourself what you are actually visualizing if it was possible.

Try not to focus on plotting but to increase your model accuracy first. A few improvements:
- scale values
- bin values
- combine features / drop features
- generate new features
- try other models: from a decision tree it will be easy to explain what features lead to what decision

Comment: This is a good answer, I just wanted to add: If plotting _is_ important, you can use dimension reduction techniques like PCA or t-SNE to reduce the feature space down to a less-accurate but more visualize-able space

Comment: @G.Anderson I am not accepting the above answer, for me getting plot is important, but I don't how to use PCA or t-SNE to get the respective plot. Do you have any concrete solution instead of a verbal answer? thanks

Comment: @tvgriek can you elaborate your answer if the coding solution is possible? I mean I want to make a plot whether the price is dropped (0) or increased for each community area. Can you provide a neat plotting solution? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to create a complete answer, but the sklearn pages for these techniques have great [examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-decomposition-plot-pca-iris-py) and there are also [articles](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualising-high-dimensional-datasets-using-pca-and-t-sne-in-python-8ef87e7915b)

Comment: @G.Anderson's suggestion you can look into indeed. Keep in mind even if you do this, it is unclear what you are visualizing. If you want to plot price drop vs. community area look into https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/barchart_demo.html

Comment: @tvgriek giving a verbal answer is not really considered as an answer, right? your meaningful answer would benefit others in `SO` community.

Comment: @Jeremy - I think the answer to your first question is beneficial. Your second question is worth a new thread and should meet https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve